# How to invoke a method on the UI thread from within a worker thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wcf, prism

I'm working on a project which uses the following technologies:

- C# (.NET 4.0)
- WCF
- PRISM 4

I'm currently making an asynchronous call to one of our Web Services using the Begin/End methods generated by a proxy. The call is successful and the client is able to receive the Web Service's response on a worker thread.

Once the response is received, I proceed to raise an event. The class subscribed to the event proceeds to request a UI navigation using PRISM:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    this.RegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.LoginContentRegion, projectSelectionViewUri)));
```

Since the asynchronous WCF response is not captured on the UI thread, I'm forced to invoke the UI thread using `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`.

The problem here is that the invoke seems to do nothing. The UI is not updated, and no exception is thrown.

How should I invoke the UI thread from within an event that is raised on a worker thread?

Edit: This question has been re-asked at the following link, since the supposed duplicate does not provide an answer:

[Request UI navigation using PRISM 4 on an asynchronous WCF response thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578346/request-ui-navigation-using-prism-4-on-an-asynchronous-wcf-response-thread)

Comment: Why was this thread closed. The possible duplicate does not deal with WPF Windows, and is nearly 3 years old, I get this is a common subject ( site wide ) but the possible duplicate as NOTHING incommon.

Comment: I agree with Ramhound...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make sure you are invoking on the actual UI `Dispatcher`, not necessarily the `Current`. You could try passing in the UI `Dispatcher`, or have some form of callback that will be handled by the UI somewhere.

Comment: How would I go about passing the UI Dispatcher ?

Comment: Assuming you create the class that requires it from some UI element (i.e. a `UserControl`), you can do something like: `var someClass = new SomeClass(this.Dispatcher);`.

Comment: @HusseinKhalil - Can you not send a reference of the main Window?

Comment: @Ramhound Passing some class a reference to the `MainWindow` is never a good solution, unless that class is going to handle some part of the `MainWindow`. If it's simply to use the `Dispatcher`, you only need to pass through the `Dispatcher`.

Comment: The problem I'm encountering is that the class which requires the dispatcher is created using PRISM (i.e.: its a View's View-Model), and so I do not directly instantiate it. I'm using UNITY to provide it with all the class references it needs using inversion of control. I tried requesting a dispatcher in the class's constructor, hoping that I would get the UI dispatcher using inversion of control (since the class is created, I assume, on the UI thread), but it didn't work.

Comment: @Slade - I will trust you when you say its not a good idea.  The only reason I would do it, is in order to get the dispatcher, thats one way I use ISyncInvok

Comment: @HusseinKhalil - You should open a new question I guess.  We need some more sample code.

Comment: Ok, two suggestions: 1. Create some class to contain a static reference to the UI `Dispatcher` (not particularly a nice approach, but should be manageable enough if done properly). 2. Post the IoC code sample your trying to use and I or someone may be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound and Slade. I like your idea of storing the UI dispatcher in a static reference... I'm not sure if its the best idea though, as you suggested. I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578346/request-ui-navigation-using-prism-4-on-an-asynchronous-wcf-response-thread